# A person is selected at random from a population that has the following characteristics

Tags: probability

A person is selected at random from a population that has the following characteristics:

```
65% of the people are men; the others are women

12% of the men are smokers

7% of the women are smokers
```

Find the chance that the selected person is a non-smoker, given that the person is a man.

(Decimal answer, please, correct to four decimal places.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Read the second line carefully. Do not be distracted by the women.

Comment: It seems that the question might be: "Find the chance that the selected person is a **man**, given that the selected person is a **non-smoker**". (task for Bayes' theorem using)

Comment: True, the real question might be that. Or perhaps that question will be asked later in the exercises. In probability/statistics courses directed to people outside the sciences, the pace is often very gentle.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the person is a men and the chance the he is smoking is 12%. Assuming that smokers and non-smokers form a partition of men, $p(smoker)+p(non-smoker)=1.$ Substitute $p(smoker)$ by it's value, $0.12, p(non-smoker)=1-0.12=0.88=88$%

Comment: Thanks Moray95, it was good, if you read again and again the Q, you understand some thing different.